# Reference to an atlas of curves and surfaces?

Tags: algebraic-curves, surfaces

I remember at more than one university math department there being a set of glass cabinets with a number of physical models of surfaces. They were all algebraic varieties on the reals (of limited degree).

I am looking for a reference (online or physical book) for a systematic listing that would show images of these surfaces.

I looked at the Mathematica site but it seemed to only have polynomial functions.

Is there an online or library reference for these?

Comment: References of probable interest include: (Online) [3D-Xplormath](http://3d-xplormath.org), particularly the [virtual math museum](http://virtualmathmuseum.org/gallery4.html); [Culture of Math exhibit](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/history/model/index.html) at Harvard; (Printed) [_Mathematische Modelle_](http://www.worldcat.org/title/mathematische-modelle-mathematical-models-from-the-collections-of-universities-and-museums/oclc/25669158) by Gerd Fischer.

Comment: If you have access to a 3D printer, you can make as many models as you want..

Comment: @bubba sure but from where? Where do you get the 3D printer designs?

Comment: @Mitch. 3D printers are driven by so-called "STL" files. These are just collections of triangles, where each triangle is represented by three 3D points. You can either write code to produce STL files yourself, or programs like Mathematica can export STL data.

Comment: @bubba oh, yes, I get that. The point of asking for an atlas is to collect all the equations and their properties in one place so that one might more easily do as you suggest.